# How to make the main scss file visible for all react components?

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass

I use `React`, `scss`.

I have main `scss` file with mixins, variables, extends etc. Currently if i want use mixins or variable i need to `@import './global.scss';` in each component directly where i want to use it. But most of the time i need these styles in almost all components `global.scss`. 
How i can make `global.scss` visible for all components without repeating import in each component directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such possibility in sass.
The solutions are:
**The first and the easiest:**
Just include @import in all sass files, it is not bad practice as you will always have control of all vars that are imported in each file in your app.

**The second**
While building you app via webpack you can find all sass files(that are not started with underscore) in your project and include you import in it.